# How to merge mysql database backups

Tags: mysql, database, merge

I have database backups taken from 2 machines(same database). ( about 75 tables)
One backup contains data from starting to 27th April 2012 and
another backup from starting to today except data from 27th April to 5th May 2012
Now i want to merge these databases. How can i do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best of with importing both databases on the same machine and do the merging via SQL commands. Say you import one dump into d1 and the other into d2, simply do

```
insert into d1.mytable (select * from d2.mytable where id not in (select id from d1.mytable));
```

or

```
replace into d1.mytable (select * from d2.mytable);
```

I'm not completely sure about the syntax and haven't tested it. But I'm sure it will at least help you to get going.